# Enable-Migrations CommandNotFoundException in VS 2015

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I created an class library (package) .Net Framework 4.5.2 in Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

I installed the EntityFramework 6.1.3. However I cant enable-migrations in the package manager console. It always complain that "CommandNotFoundExceptions"

```
enable-migrations : The term 'enable-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ enable-migrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enable-migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

Below are some of the efforts to get this working

1. Reinstall the EntityFramework , restart VS with admin previlege
2. Reinstall the EntityFramework with -IncludePreRelease
3. Tried to install Migrators.EF6.Tools - this is not compatible with .Net 4.5.2
4. Install EntityFramework.Commands

None of the above worked for me.

This is my project.json

```
 "frameworks": {
    "net451": { }

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "LetsBreakIT.Pattern.EF6": "1.0.0-*"
  }
```

Anything that I am missing?

-Alan-